# Не работает сравнение

Tags: javascript, if, сравнение, калькулятор

```
 if(this.value == total)
```

Делаю калькулятор.
И при нажатии на кнопку '=' должно идти просчитывание операции.
но нет.

Вот целиком JS

```js
$(function() {
  let display = $('div.display').text(),
    total = '=',
    plus = '+',
    minus = '-',
    multy = '*',
    del = '/',
    clear = 'C';

  console.log(typeof(display), display);

  $('.btn').on('click', function() {
    display = display + this.value;
    $('div.display').text('').text(display);
  });
  $('.btn-spec').on('click', function() {
    if (this.value == total) {
      console.log(display);
    } else {
      console.log(this.value);
      console.log(total);
      display = display + ' ' + this.value + ' ';
      $('div.display').text('').text(display);
    }
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 1200px;
  /* Ширина */
  /* outline: 1px solid #787274; /* Временная рамка */
  padding: 0px;
  /* Внутренний отступ */
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Выравнивание по центру экрана монитора */
}

#header {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 80px;
  /* Высота */
  background: #25b33f;
  /* Фоновый цвет */
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /* Отступ снизу */
  z-index: 101;
  position: fixed;
}

#sidebar {
  padding-top: 90px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #9cb39a;
  /* Фоновый цвет */
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /* Отступ снизу */
  float: right;
}

#content {
  padding-top: 90px;
  height: 600px;
  width: 980px;
  background: #98b32c;
  /* Фоновый цвет */
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /* Отступ снизу */
}

#footer {
  height: 80px;
  /* Высота */
  background: #41874e;
  /* Фоновый цвет */
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  /* Отступ снизу */
}

.calculator-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #5fc1ee;
}

.calculator-wrapper .display {
  height: 60px;
  width: auto;
  border: 2px red solid;
  text-align: right;
  display: block;
}

.calculator-wrapper .history {
  display: none;
  border: 2px red solid;
}

.calculator-wrapper .btn,
.btn-spec {
  font-size: large;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Каркас сайта</title>
  <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <!--Оболочка-->
    <div id="header">
      <img src="1212.png" alt="123">
    </div>
    <!--Шапка-->
    <div>
      <div id="sidebar">
        <ul>todo
          <li>calculator</li>
          <li>todo list</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--Сайдбар-->

      <div id="content">
        <div class="calculator-wrapper">
          <div class="display"></div>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td><input class="btn" type="button" value="1"></td>
              <td><input class="btn" type="button" value="2"></td>
              <td><input class="btn" type="button" value="3"></td>
              <td><input class="btn-spec" type="button" value="*"></td>

              <tr>
                <td><input class="btn" type="button" value="4"></td>
                <td><input class="btn" type="button" value="5"></td>
                <td><input class="btn" type="button" value="6"></td>
                <td><input class="btn-spec" type="button" value="/"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input class="btn" type="button" value="7"></td>
                <td><input class="btn" type="button" value="8"></td>
                <td><input class="btn" type="button" value="9"></td>
                <td><input class="btn-spec" type="button" value="C"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input class="btn-spec" type="button" value="+"></td>
                <td><input class="btn" type="button" value="0"></td>
                <td><input class="btn-spec" type="button" value="-"></td>
                <td><input class="btn-spec" type="button" value="="></td>
              </tr>


          </table>
          <div class="history">
            history
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--Контент-->
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
    <!--Подвал-->
  </div>
  <script src="../../js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/default.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Подскажите, где и что не так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

собственно вычисления нигде и нету, ты просто выводишь строку. а сравнение работает

```js
$(function() {
  let display = $('div.display').text(),
    total = '=',
    plus = '+',
    minus = '-',
    multy = '*',
    del = '/',
    clear = 'C';

  console.log(typeof(display), display);

  $('.btn').on('click', function() {
    display = display + this.value;
    $('div.display').text('').text(display);
  });
  $('.btn-spec').on('click', function() {
    if (this.value == total) {
      console.log(eval(display));
    } else {
      console.log(this.value);
      console.log(total);
      display = display + ' ' + this.value + ' ';
      $('div.display').text('').text(display);
    }
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 1200px;
  /* Ширина */
  /* outline: 1px solid #787274; /* Временная рамка */
  padding: 0px;
  /* Внутренний отступ */
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Выравнивание по центру экрана монитора */
}

#header {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 80px;
  /* Высота */
  background: #25b33f;
  /* Фоновый цвет */
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /* Отступ снизу */
  z-index: 101;
  position: fixed;
}

#sidebar {
  padding-top: 90px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #9cb39a;
  /* Фоновый цвет */
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /* Отступ снизу */
  float: right;
}

#content {
  padding-top: 90px;
  height: 600px;
  width: 980px;
  background: #98b32c;
  /* Фоновый цвет */
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /* Отступ снизу */
}

#footer {
  height: 80px;
  /* Высота */
  background: #41874e;
  /* Фоновый цвет */
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  /* Отступ снизу */
}

.calculator-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #5fc1ee;
}

.calculator-wrapper .display {
  height: 60px;
  width: auto;
  border: 2px red solid;
  text-align: right;
  display: block;
}

.calculator-wrapper .history {
  display: none;
  border: 2px red solid;
}

.calculator-wrapper .btn,
.btn-spec {
  font-size: large;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Каркас сайта</title>
  <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <!--Оболочка-->
    <div id="header">
      <img src="1212.png" alt="123">
    </div>
    <!--Шапка-->
    <div>
      <div id="sidebar">
        <ul>todo
          <li>calculator</li>
          <li>todo list</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--Сайдбар-->

      <div id="content">
        <div class="calculator-wrapper">
          <div class="display"></div>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td><input class="btn" type="button" value="1"></td>
              <td><input class="btn" type="button" value="2"></td>
              <td><input class="btn" type="button" value="3"></td>
              <td><input class="btn-spec" type="button" value="*"></td>

              <tr>
                <td><input class="btn" type="button" value="4"></td>
                <td><input class="btn" type="button" value="5"></td>
                <td><input class="btn" type="button" value="6"></td>
                <td><input class="btn-spec" type="button" value="/"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input class="btn" type="button" value="7"></td>
                <td><input class="btn" type="button" value="8"></td>
                <td><input class="btn" type="button" value="9"></td>
                <td><input class="btn-spec" type="button" value="C"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input class="btn-spec" type="button" value="+"></td>
                <td><input class="btn" type="button" value="0"></td>
                <td><input class="btn-spec" type="button" value="-"></td>
                <td><input class="btn-spec" type="button" value="="></td>
              </tr>


          </table>
          <div class="history">
            history
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--Контент-->
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
    <!--Подвал-->
  </div>
  <script src="../../js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/default.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо. 
Совсем забыл про eval.